# How to visualize attributes of nodes in graph in Networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

In Networkx, I am trying to add properties to each node of the graph that I want to create. These attributes are besides the label nodes. Is it possible to visually see the properties of each node in the plot of graph?

Here is the code that I have tried so far but in the plot, I can't see any extra attributes that I have added. Is there any way in networkx that I can visualize the graph with the label of each node and if I click on the each node the attributes of node are shown?

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

edges = pd.DataFrame({'source' : [0, 1],
                      'target' : [1, 2],
                      'weight' : [100, 50]})

nodes = pd.DataFrame({'node' : [0, 1, 2],
                      'name' : ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'],
                      'gender' : ['M', 'F', 'M']})

G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(edges, 'source', 'target', 'weight')
nx.set_node_attributes(G, 'gender', pd.Series(nodes.gender, index=nodes.node).to_dict())
nx.draw(G, font_weight='bold', linewidths=0.25, font_size=8, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```